# Drupal 8: Extend user class

Tags: class, inheritance, module, drupal-8

Is there any way to extend User class form a custom module?
I need to create a custom user class (e.g. **Mymodule\User**) that will use/override the existing User class methods or add some other custom methods.

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to implement [hook_entity_type_build().](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_type_build/8.5.x)

Create a new class in your module that extends `\Drupal\user\Entity\User`.

```
use Drupal\user\Entity\User as BaseUser;

class MyUser extends BaseUser {
}
```

Then replace existing class with yours

```
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeInterface;

/**
 * @param EntityTypeInterface[] $entity_types
 */
function my_module_entity_type_build(&$entity_types) {
  if (isset($entity_types['user'])) {
    $entity_types['user']->setClass('Drupal\my_module\Entity\MyUser');
  }
}
```

Make sure you rebuild your caches.

Comment: Great. Can you confirm the answer :)

Comment: Minor improvement. Don't forget the  `namespace Drupal\my_module\Entity;` at the top of the class file.